# Error during trigger execution: Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created a trigger which must update the total amount from Account table. Whenever some data is update from Sale table, the trigger executes a store procedure calculating the current amount and inserting it into Account, but when it's about to update the Account table, some quite strange error occurs:

> The data in row 5 was not committed Error Source: .Net SqlClient
>   DataProvider Error Message: Error converting data type nvarchar to
>   bigint. The statement have been terminated.

Below there is the Sale's trigger script:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Trigger_Sale]
ON [dbo].[Sale]
FOR DELETE, INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    exec ComputeAccountAmount ID_Account
END
```

And the procedure `ComputeAccountAmount`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ComputeAccountAmount]
@IdAccount bigint
AS
begin transaction
    update Account set AccountAmount = (SELECT sum(AmountSold) 
        from Sale
        where @IdAccount = ID_Account)
    where @IdAccount = ID_Account
commit
```

I've already checked out all the types the procedures uses, yet its tables and everything is bigint as shown below:

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Account] (
    [ID_Account]     BIGINT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [ExpireDate]     DATE   NOT NULL,
    [PurchaseLimit]  MONEY  NOT NULL,
    [OpeningDate]    DATE   NOT NULL,
    [ID_Customer]    INT    NOT NULL,
    [AccountAmount]  MONEY  NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Account] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID_Account] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Account_Customer] FOREIGN KEY ([ID_Customer]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Customer] ([ID_Customer]) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Sale] (
    [ID_Sale]    INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [SaleDate]   DATE NOT NULL,
    [AmountSold] MONEY        NOT NULL,
    [ID_Account] BIGINT       NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID_Account] ASC)
);
```

For testing, I'm using the Visual Studio to manually verify the trigger. What's going on?

Comment: Edit your question and include the definitions of the two tables.

Comment: Your `Sale` table has no `ID_Account` in it.

Comment: Doesn't have a `Total` in it either.

Comment: Sorry, I had to translate the code which was in Portuguese.

Comment: Are you able to test the trigger by manually inserting a row in Management Studio? Does it work if you do that?

Comment: What is this? `exec ComputeAccountAmount ID_Account` What is `ID_Account` is your trigger?

Comment: My guess is same as @GiorgiNakeuri script.your trigger script is incomplete.If this do not solve then you can thoroughly check if there are any other dependencies on these two table which is doing the trick .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously you have syntax error in your trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Trigger_Sale]
ON [dbo].[Sale]
FOR DELETE, INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    exec ComputeAccountAmount ID_Account
END
```

What is `ID_Account`? It will throw an error

[image]

You need to select distinct accountIDs from `INSERTED` and `DELETED` tables in your trigger and for each of this account call `exec ComputeAccountAmount`. Something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Trigger_Sale] ON [dbo].[Sale]
    FOR DELETE, INSERT, UPDATE
AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @AccountID BIGINT

        DECLARE trCur CURSOR FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY
        FOR
            SELECT  AccountID FROM    DELETED
            UNION
            SELECT  AccountID FROM    INSERTED

        OPEN trCur

        FETCH NEXT FROM trCur INTO @AccountID

        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
            BEGIN

                EXEC ComputeAccountAmount @AccountID

                FETCH NEXT FROM trCur INTO @AccountID

            END

        CLOSE trCur
        DEALLOCATE trCur
    END
```

Comment: Giorgi, your answer worked pretty well! But how come hasn't my solution worked? It can be simple, but I'm new to some database concepts. Thanks!

Comment: In your trigger you had just `ID_Account`. You know that it is table column but SQL SERVER doesn't. You can not pass column to stored procedure. You should pass value of that column to procedure.